# Linq converting implicitly to type

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have following method with linq statement in it.

```
public prO Getproject(int id)
{    
      var tt = (from c in db.pdi
                where c.id==id
                select new prO
                {
                    name = c.p.name,
                    pr_id = c.p.pr_id,
                    re = c.p.re                              
                });
      return tt;
 }
```

The above method returns one value of tt. However I keep getting intelicense error 
(local variable) `IQueryable<prO>tt`
Error:

```
cannot implicitly convert system.linq.iqueryable to prO
```

Please let me know how to this error. Thanks

Comment: I'd use `SingleOrDefault` or `Single` myself, since he's filtering on `id`.

Comment: Just to be clear, LINQ is not converting anything implicitly to any type here, the types you mention are very explicit.

Comment: @Rawling filtering on ID is almost always when I use FirstOrDefault. Assuming you have a setup that makes ID's unique (e.g. A PK in the database), it makes sense to use FirstOrDefault as it'll break as soon as it finds a match, rather than continue to iterate the collection.

Comment: @Joeb If you're using a PK in the database, the DB will not be iterating. I'd rather enforce the uniqueness in my code too. If someone breaks the database enough that it allows duplicate values in the column I'm assuming is unique, I'd rather have my code throw an exception early rather than continue to look like it's working until the lack of uniqueness causes a real issue somewhere else.

Comment: @Joeb454 The where clause will hopefully hit an index if you are querying for a PK, ergo `Single()` would provide a better behavior with exceptions since something is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a collection with your query.
Since you want only one item change your query to:

```
public prO Getproject(int id)
{    
      var tt = (from c in db.pdi
                where c.id==id
                select new prO
                {
                    name = c.p.name,
                    pr_id = c.p.pr_id,
                    re = c.p.re   
                //change here                           
                }).FirstOrDefault();
      return tt;
 }
```

The error tells you the following: Your method has a return type of `prO`, but your query doe not return this type. You are nowhere defining, that you are returning excatly one item of `prO`. As far as the compiler is concerned, there could be 1000 items with a matching Id.

*EDIT:*
Based on Rawlings comments, it would be preferrable to use `SingleOrDefault()` instead. Both solutions are per se working, the difference however is that `FirstOrDefault` returns any amount of results, but takes only the first one, whereas `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` lets the query itself return exactly a single item.

Note, that if your query returns *more* than 1 result, FirstOrDefault displays the first result. SingleOrDefault will throw an exception.

Comment: If you use `First` rather than `Single`, there could *still* be 1000 items with a matching ID, and you'd never know.

Comment: True Enough, but the OP hasn't provided that information either

Comment: @Rawling SO let's you edit posts, you could always do just that.

Comment: @jdphenix No, I'm not going to edit someone else's answer to make it match what I think it should be, and I hope you wouldn't either.

Comment: I'll add your suggestion to my answer Rawling - Edit: Done.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, whether `Single` or `First` actually modifies the (sql?) query is dependent on the database driver, the MS SQL driver does not modify the query, but rather does the full select and fetches everything and then checks for `Count() > 1` and throws for `Single`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `return tt.FirstOrDefault();`